# Symfony 3.4 WebServerBundle PHP version

Tags: symfony

I have both php7.0 and php7.1 installed on Ubuntu.
Both CLI and Apache are switched to use 7.1

```
php -v
PHP 7.1.14-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Feb  9 2018 
09:33:27) ( NTS )
```

but the built-in http server of Symfony still uses 7.0

```
PHP Version 7.0.27-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
System  Linux spring.home.lan 4.4.0-112-generic #135-Ubuntu SMP Fri 
Jan 19 11:48:36 UTC 2018 x86_64
Build Date  Jan 5 2018 14:12:46
Server API  Built-in HTTP server
```

Any suggestions what is wrong?

Comment: How do you know 7.0 is being used by the server?  phpinfo() ?

Comment: phpinfo(), Symfony Profiler and problems with some 3rd party libs.

Comment: And you are doing bin/console server:start?  Didn't modify console? I suppose you could try php bin/console but it does seem odd.

Comment: Looks like your path is still pointing to old version. Try `/usr/bin/env php -v` and see what you get.